# Scala console: OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: scala, jvm, erlang, elixir, beam

Scala:

```
(1 to 100000000).toList.foldLeft(0)((acc, x) => acc + x)
```

Elixir:

```
1..100000000 |> Enum.to_list |> List.foldl(0, fn x, acc -> x + acc end)
```

They are of the same functionality. However, JVM just throws GC outrage exception in the contrast that BEAM could handle it safely. I'm just curious why JVM couldn't handle this situation? Is it the fault of JVM or just Scala Compiler?  (I know I could use Stream or View to handle this situation)

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to increase heap size? There is no such thing as "JVM is better than BEAM overall", they are orange and apple.

Comment: _JVM is better than BEAM overall_ but can't allocate a list of 100000000 and overflow integer. LOL.

Comment: _“JVM is better than BEAM overall”_ downvoted for that.

Comment: Having the same functionality is not the same as having the same implementation. In this case your Scala code has an unnecessary call to `toList` which is the cause of the problem. The Elixir code may well be implemented in a different way that would avoid the problem even if it is run on the JVM.

Comment: I'm a bit conflicted on this one "JVM is better than BEAM overall" is hardly a technical conversation and I'm tempted to vote close for that alone.  However, since there's a bit about Laziness and Scala this question isn't totally lacking value.  Be careful @chenyuandong about value judgments in tech work.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci My apologize. I tag it with <del>.

Comment: I rescinded my down vote.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Elixir handles this operation, but the `toList` will create a real List object with 100000000 entries. If you skip that step, the operation will succeed in Scala as well:

```
scala> (1 to 100000000).foldLeft(0)((acc,x) => acc + x)
res1: Int = 987459712
```

Comment: It is true, because 1 to N is lazy. And the result is wrong (it exceeds the range of Int type).

Comment: Yeah, but why does a real List object with 100000000 entries of Boxed Integer just explode the GC? It is some kind of problem.

Comment: You can fix the integer overflow by using `BigInt`: 
`(1 to 100000000).foldLeft(BigInt(0))((acc,x) => acc + x)`

Comment: Right, right. It is not the key part of my problem.

Comment: Guessing from the stacktrace and the error message, it could be that the `toList` method doesn't allocate the resulting list at once, but increases its size again and again. And thereby creates so much garbage that the VM spends most time in GC, which then leads to the observed exception.

Comment: This can be simplified to `(1 to 100000000).sum`

Comment: @Harald I don't think so. `ListBuffer` isn't inefficient that way